# VS2010 - automaticly add colon when writing CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to make Visual Studio 2010 automaticly add colon after selecting property name when writing CSS code?

Same as Adobe Dreamweaver does?

Answer (score 1):

Using Resharper will help, it has very beautiful intellisense support for CSS. I am not sure if it adds colon automatically.

Comment: R# is a very nice tool indeed but it does not automatically add colon to code.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) plugin for VS2012 has this functionality (and I use it). I don't know for sure if **[Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) for VS2010** has this too, but you can try.

After plugin install go to: Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials -> CSS -> Enable Speed Typing (TRUE)